# Regexp for a sequence of complex Prefix-suffix pairs?

Tags: regex

I would need a regexp that would validate a space-separated list of IDs, each ID can be:

- an integer digit
- any-character sequence followed by "-" (dash) and then by integer digit.

  ```
  12 
  ABCD-124
  ```

and not allowed cases are:

- any-character sequence that is NOT integer digit and NOT followed by BOTH dash and integer digit. Dash itself after the sequence is NOT enough to be validated.

  ```
  ABCD-
  ABDCE
  ```

I especially need help to understand how to do optional check, for the "any character plus dash" part before integer part.

Comment: great and where is the regex you tried?

Comment: @AmitJoki added a question I have in particular.

Comment: Are the characters always going to be alphabets in uppercase?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding optional "*any character plus dash*": you can use `\S` (anuthing that is not space) since you are not allowing spaces in the input. A dash (or is it a hyphen as in your example?) can be matched with simple `-`. To make this group optional, put it into a non-capturing group and add a `?` quantifier.

I think you are looking for this regex:

```
^(?:\S+-)?\d+$
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wQ6vE8/2).

[image]

P.S. To get rid of downvotes, please always provide something that you tried and explain what does not work. Show that you are active.

Comment: That's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use this RegEx: `/([A-Z]+)?-?[0-9]+/`

[RegEx Demo and Explanation](https://www.regex101.com/r/mG6mZ0/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use : `(\w+-)?\d+`

Explanation:

- `(\w+-)?` => Any character sequence followed by `-` (zero or one occurrences)
- `\d+` => Integer digits

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xW7kJ1/2)